# LiDAR dataset displaying 500 meters to the east of correct position

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, lidar

Why does my LIDAR dataset show up ~500 meters to the east of the correct position even though a spatial reference/coordinate system is provided?

Some background:

1. The LIDAR data were downloaded from the USGS website as .zip files
2. Unzipped, the .las files have an associated .xml file with correct coordinates for tile position (UL Corner, UR Corner etc.)
3. Projected coordinate system (State Plane NAD 1983 Florida East Meters) is listed in .xml
4. The FL County layer in the image below is in the correct location.

How can I permanently bind the projection/spatial information to the .las file (not need the separate manually created .prj file)? I'm trying to use the LAStools (from lastools.org). When I use the `LASclip`, the clipping polygon is in the correct location but arcmap thinks the .las file is 500 meters east still, so nothing (or everything) gets clipped.

[image: text in .xml]

[image]

Comment: EPSG:2881 is in US feet, not meters, which matches the proj  defn too. Does the cty layer have a defined crs?

Comment: The county layer is in WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_17N

Comment: I added a .prj file from spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nad83harn-florida-east-ftus to the folder the .las files are in (with the same file name).  The two tiles that I manually added a .prj file for are showing in the correct location!  Unfortunately, I have 100's of .LAS files and don't completely understand why adding the .prj file and defining projection in ArcMap aren't doing the same thing.  Because it's for the .lasd maybe?

Comment: The LASD has its own projection with each dataset within having its own (or none) projection. If the projection is defined correctly and the transformation is applied (if required) then ArcMap will project on the fly; it's not ideal to have LiDAR data in a different coordinate system to the map as that's a lot of on-the-fly coordinate transformations for each map refresh. In the LASD you can set each las files' projection without the need for prj files: go to the files' properties and change it there.

Comment: That's ok @AndreSilva, perhaps next week i'll have some time.